# matplotlib: Use fixed number of decimals with scientific notation in tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the y ticks in this small example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([200,400,600,800])
plt.ticklabel_format(axis='y',style='sci',scilimits=(0,0))
plt.show()
```

Resulting plot: [image: tack.imgur.com/Gnl6F.png]

I would like the y tick labels to have a fixed format with one decimal, i.e., `1.0` instead of `1`, etc. How can I do that while keeping the exponent for the scientific notation on top of the plot?

All solutions I've found so far (most using `FormatStrFormatter` instead of `ScalarFormatter`) make the exponent repeat on all tick labels, like `1.0e2`, `2.0e2`, etc., which is not what I want.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I've just found a solution. Here it goes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

class ScalarFormatterForceFormat(ScalarFormatter):
    def _set_format(self,vmin,vmax):  # Override function that finds format to use.
        self.format = "%1.1f"  # Give format here

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([200,400,600,800])

yfmt = ScalarFormatterForceFormat()
yfmt.set_powerlimits((0,0))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(yfmt)            

plt.show()
```

It was based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42156450/9512772) on a different thread.